# Terraform authorisation error creating AWS EventBridge connection to API Destinations

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-event-bridge

How to fix this?
`Error: creating EventBridge connection (xxxxx): ValidationException: Failed to create the connection(s). Failed to create the secret because the user is not authorized to perform the operation on secret 'events!connection/xxxx/xxxx'. [...] status code: 400, request id: xxxx`

The relevant Terraform code defined:

- An EventBridge rule (`aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`)
- An EventBridge target (`aws_cloudwatch_event_target`) that references a rule name and a destination ARN.
- An API Destination (`aws_cloudwatch_event_api_destination`) that specifies an external webhook URL but is also required (by Terraform AWS provider) to reference a connection ARN.
- A connection (`aws_cloudwatch_event_connection`):

The particular webhook does not actually require any authentication, so the connection was specified as:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_connection" "this" {
  name               = "xxx"
  authorization_type = "API_KEY"
  auth_parameters {
    api_key {
      key   = "Dummy"
      value = "None"   }}}
```

Is the problem that the Terraform role itself needs additional privileges, or that the `.tf` file needs to additionally define policies associated with these particular resources?

Comment: The aws credentials which are used to run your terraform code to create the resources is missing permissions for even connections. This error is coming from aws not terraform.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html) for AWS EventBridge API Destinations include the note:

*To successfully create or update a connection, you must use an account that has permission to use Secrets Manager...*

It also references a suggested best-practice (at least for OAuth credentials and when using CloudFormation) that is to manually create a secret (in Secrets Manager) and then reference it from the infra-code. However, it doesn't appear that the Terraform AWS provider currently supports this pattern.

(Incidentally, it would be possible to achieve the same effect without increasing Terraform permissions by instead using a Lambda or SSM Automation executeScript to perform the HTTP request, also gaining more control of how the event is communicated.)